# The "interior" of a convex set?

Tags: gn.general-topology, convexity, convex-analysis

Consider any compact metric space $S$ which is a convex subset of a vector space. I am trying to see if the following definition is equivalent/close to some well-known definitions.

Consider a convex subset $A\subsetneq S$. Let the "convex interior" of $A$ (I made the name up), denoted as $\text{ci}(A)$, be defined as follows:
$$
\text{ci}(A)=\{a\in A| \exists \epsilon\in(0,1) \text{ and } b\not\in A \text{ such that } \epsilon a+(1-\epsilon) b \in A\}.
$$

It is not hard to see that $\text{int}(A)\subseteq \text{ci}(A)$. But in certain cases $\text{ci}(A)$ is a larger set. For example, let $S$ be the unit square in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $A=\{(x,y)\in S| 0.1\le x\le 0.2\}$. Here $\text{ci}(A)=A$.

Comment: I'm not certain what your question is.  It seems that if you write down a condition for "interior" you will have answered your own question.  But if you have no criterion for interior, your question can not be answered.

Comment: I am mainly asking if this definition is well known or equivalent to some well-known definitions.

Comment: I see the following cases: 1. A is an affine subspace, in which case there are no convex interior points. 2. A is a pointed cone in which case the cusp is the only ci point. 3. All other cases, in which every point is ci.

Comment: The weird thing about this definition is that it is non-local. As the cone shows, if I know $A$ only in a neighborhood of $a$, then there are cases where I cannot decide if $a\in ci(A)$ or not. Possibly a more natural condition would be "For all $b\notin A$, there exists $\epsilon$", but I think that should be equivalent to the topological interior. Maybe the important question is, what are you trying to achieve with this definition?

Comment: In Köthe's book *Topological Vector Spaces* there is a notion of *internal* points of a convex set $A$ which means that $x$ is an interior point of the intersection of $A$ with every real line through $x$ (of course, *interior* refers to the usual topology of the reals).

Comment: if that was for all b (rather than exist) that would be the definition of relative interior for convex set A.